# Is there any situation where, in a blueprint structure, a publication has as a "direct" parent, the parent of its parent?

Tags: blueprint

I found a very special blueprint hierarchy where a publication has two parents, being one of them parent of the other. Here is a graphic representation of what I am talking about:
[image]

I had never seen something like this and I am thinking of possible scenarios where this make sense, so calling for all those Business Analysts and Functional Consultants to give it a thought and share with me.

Thank you.

**Additional Information:** This publications are all content publications, and are not used for a multi-language situation. In fact the website is in English-only and has no blueprint design for multi-language.

Comment: If the same content exists in both A and B, publication C will inherit it from Pub A in this case. Whether that is sensible depends on the roles of the publications.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; you see this structure in multicountry multilanguage implementation (although not as directly as in your image); imagine for example the following case:

[image]

To have the Dutch website's main language in Dutch the English version would have to re-inherit the overridden English content.

KLM uses this model; I tend to advise customers to have the "main" site for a country in the "main" language for the blueprint (and not the countries "main" language).

Comment: It does not cover the specific scenario that Jaime is mentioning.

Comment: In your case it makes sense, but in mine which we are only dealing with content publications and there is no multi-language, A --> B, B --> C, A --> C, does not make sense, I don-t see what's the benefit of filtering Content from A to C, through B, when priority is "1" from A to C. Only local/localized content would be inherited from B, and since you are not translating (or making "local" changes"), I don't see the point.

Comment: Not exactly; B adds to C but cannot override A; as such this is an "add but not change" scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I have seen this twice and I had hard time describing that this does not make any sense to me as I can't see a benefit of inheriting the Publication C from publication A at all.

1. If we have some items in A, publication B will already have them inherited and just inheriting C from B will make them available in C.
2. **Updated As per Bjorn's comment:** If the Item from A are localized in B, then C will have that item from A - This will only be the only scenario where A is useful
3. If the items are created new in B, then C will automatically have it from B and no need to inherit from A

I hope it helps.

Comment: Same thoughts here...

Comment: For #2, wouldn't you have a BluePrint chain "tie" (1-step) from C to both A and to B? The BluePrint priority applies in the case of ties and A would "win" (matching what @Frank describes in his comment).

Comment: Exactly; this blueprint structure reads as "C has everything from both A and B but if something is in both take from A" in other words this disallows editors working in B to override content from A in publication C but C will still have everything they added.

Comment: @Alvin: In case of a Blueprint tie; for an item which is also localized - Localization will win over the priority - so despite of Priority 1 of A, it will be B with Priority 2 will win.

Comment: @Pankaj: I thought the rule was "shortest path to local item" in which case A wins over B as the path length is 1 for both in which case the priority is the tie breaker...

Comment: Agreed with you Bjorn...My Mistake; answer has been updated :)

Answer (score 1):

See my comment.

If it's not an accident, this setup tells me B can add things for use in C (but maybe not access C) while at the same time, they can see and use A, but not change how A is shared to C.

I'd vote special type of editors, an integration, or some kind of "test" Publications. Even for English-only sites, maybe folders and permission might be a better fit since this isn't for localization. You could ask the BluePrint designer.

Comment: Yeah... you (IMHO) normally don't create a publication for these things, you should use Folder rights and permissions... But very useful "reason", since it helps me my point that these scenarios don't apply in "my" blueprint, hence, makes no sense...

Comment: The BluePrint training describes some scenarios for same-language, separate content Publications for maybe an Intranet or separate divisions. There's a trade-off for translation and sharing so you do need a good business decision for the setup. As for "making sense," I usually see things like this when they _mostly_ work and don't break anything. It's like authorization--a user might get the right access with fewer groups, but I'll occasionally see a user with more-than-needed.